# Getting attributes from JSON arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.5

I'm trying to get the first attribute element in the JSON list. This data is from the operational layer which I am able to parse through. However, I can't seem to get the `attributes` from the first element. I have tried using

```
featureSet = feature[0]['attributes']
```

but i get an error about `string indices must be zero`

```
featureSet = {
    "featureSet": {
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
        "features": [
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "rings": [[[-13181314.619257905, 4031321.0901253144], [-13181350.20476163, 4031296.6641790946], [-13181358.492278388, 4031309.344139285], [-13181322.662721818, 4031333.3909452674], [-13181314.619257905, 4031321.0901253144]]],
                    "spatialReference": {
                        "wkid": 102100,
                        "latestWkid": 3857
                    }
                },
                 //gotta get the attribute data here!
                "attributes": {
                    "AIN": "4252029026",
                    "Ref_ID": 5448,
                    "Auto_Trash_Route": "FRI-AA-09",
                    "Auto_Recycle_Route": "FRI-AR-03",
                    "Auto_Yard_Route": "FRI-AY-08",
                    "Semi_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Semi_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Semi_Yard_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Yard_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Yard_Route": null,
                    "District": "WLA",
                    "Auto_Trash_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Auto_Recycle_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Auto_Yard_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Conflict_Type": null,
                    "Collection_Day": "FRI",
                    "Auto_HM_Route": null,
                    "Semi_HM_Route": null,
                    "Manual_HM_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_HM_Route": null,
                    "Count_SL": 1,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Trash_lbs": 35.9,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Yard_lbs": 14.6,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Recycle_lbs": 8.4,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Recycle_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Recyle_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Recyle_lbs": null,
                    "Parcel_With_SL": "YES",
                    "created_user": null,
                    "created_date": null,
                    "last_edited_user": null,
                    "last_edited_date": null,
                    "OBJECTID": 37566,
                    "Trash_Can_Count": null,
                    "Recycle_Can_Count": null,
                    "Yard_Can_Count": null,
                    "HM_Can_Count": null,
                    "GlobalID": "{31C8857B-DF44-49FB-B278-0FF2A62691F9}"
                },
                "symbol": {
                    "color": [247, 137, 216, 255],
                    "outline": {
                        "color": [153, 153, 153, 255],
                        "width": 0.35123494768229474,
                        "type": "esriSLS",
                        "style": "esriSLSSolid"
                    },
                    "type": "esriSFS",
                    "style": "esriSFSSolid"
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "rings": [[[-13181330.698957343, 4031345.688170007], [-13181366.75393292, 4031321.9725121553], [-13181368.842310982, 4031320.5985230785], [-13181370.173164586, 4031322.656038063], [-13181377.899381213, 4031334.6075920546], [-13181339.67132035, 4031359.649699868], [-13181330.698957343, 4031345.688170007]]],
                    "spatialReference": {
                        "wkid": 102100,
                        "latestWkid": 3857
                    }
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "AIN": "4252029028",
                    "Ref_ID": 37671,
                    "Auto_Trash_Route": "FRI-AA-09",
                    "Auto_Recycle_Route": "FRI-AR-03",
                    "Auto_Yard_Route": "FRI-AY-08",
                    "Semi_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Semi_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Semi_Yard_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Yard_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Yard_Route": null,
                    "District": "WLA",
                    "Auto_Trash_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Auto_Recycle_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Auto_Yard_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Conflict_Type": null,
                    "Collection_Day": "FRI",
                    "Auto_HM_Route": null,
                    "Semi_HM_Route": null,
                    "Manual_HM_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_HM_Route": null,
                    "Count_SL": 4,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Trash_lbs": 143.6,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Yard_lbs": 58.4,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Recycle_lbs": 33.6,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Recycle_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Recyle_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Recyle_lbs": null,
                    "Parcel_With_SL": "YES",
                    "created_user": null,
                    "created_date": null,
                    "last_edited_user": null,
                    "last_edited_date": null,
                    "OBJECTID": 37584,
                    "Trash_Can_Count": null,
                    "Recycle_Can_Count": null,
                    "Yard_Can_Count": null,
                    "HM_Can_Count": null,
                    "GlobalID": "{A4C67FD5-291B-41D7-B7A2-75CBA6128592}"
                },
                "symbol": {
                    "color": [247, 137, 216, 255],
                    "outline": {
                        "color": [153, 153, 153, 255],
                        "width": 0.35123494768229474,
                        "type": "esriSLS",
                        "style": "esriSLSSolid"
                    },
                    "type": "esriSFS",
                    "style": "esriSFSSolid"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "rings": [[[-13181388.563268814, 4031729.492638631], [-13181402.481782483, 4031720.197843957], [-13181416.403888388, 4031710.902903584], [-13181440.166447477, 4031747.331963275], [-13181412.322025921, 4031765.9182002395], [-13181388.563268814, 4031729.492638631]]],
                    "spatialReference": {
                        "wkid": 102100,
                        "latestWkid": 3857
                    }
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "AIN": "4252033013",
                    "Ref_ID": 65813,
                    "Auto_Trash_Route": "FRI-AA-09",
                    "Auto_Recycle_Route": "FRI-AR-03",
                    "Auto_Yard_Route": "FRI-AY-08",
                    "Semi_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Semi_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Semi_Yard_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Manual_Yard_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Trash_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Recycle_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_Yard_Route": null,
                    "District": "WLA",
                    "Auto_Trash_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Auto_Recycle_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Auto_Yard_Route_Overlap": null,
                    "Conflict_Type": null,
                    "Collection_Day": "FRI",
                    "Auto_HM_Route": null,
                    "Semi_HM_Route": null,
                    "Manual_HM_Route": null,
                    "Satellite_HM_Route": null,
                    "Count_SL": 1,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Trash_lbs": 35.9,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Yard_lbs": 14.6,
                    "Avg_Weight_Auto_Recycle_lbs": 8.4,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Semi_Recycle_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Manual_Recyle_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Trash_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Yard_lbs": null,
                    "Avg_Weight_Satellite_Recyle_lbs": null,
                    "Parcel_With_SL": "YES",
                    "created_user": null,
                    "created_date": null,
                    "last_edited_user": null,
                    "last_edited_date": null,
                    "OBJECTID": 37599,
                    "Trash_Can_Count": null,
                    "Recycle_Can_Count": null,
                    "Yard_Can_Count": null,
                    "HM_Can_Count": null,
                    "GlobalID": "{E72B4B37-F6F0-40A7-BC1A-D494B9A98D8D}"
                },
                "symbol": {
                    "color": [247, 137, 216, 255],
                    "outline": {
                        "color": [153, 153, 153, 255],
                        "width": 0.35123494768229474,
                        "type": "esriSLS",
                        "style": "esriSLSSolid"
                    },
                    "type": "esriSFS",
                    "style": "esriSFSSolid"
                }
            }   
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Close, try  `myAttributes =featureSet['featureSet']['features'][0]['attributes']`

Comment: didnt work. Got error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Hmmm, is your `featureSet` variable a dict? Do a `type(featureSet)`. If its returning a STR, You'll need to either get that as a dict (json) or convert to it.

Comment: I have converted `featureSet` as a dict with the json library.

Comment: The dictionary has extra 'u'  between where there is spaces when it is converted to a dict by the json but i still cant get the first attribute in the list

Comment: @Demon You need to specify the attribute that you want the value extracted from or declare featureSet as a list or array example to get at the attribute AIN = featureSet['featureSet'][0]['attributes']['AIN']